# Javascript - How to display whole number with one decimal point after being rounded

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

I am using a mapping function to return rounded decimal points. There are a few number that returns a whole number such as `index 2. 4 and index 3. 1` I am attempting to have these single digit numbers return with a decimal point. So for example, having `index 2: 4 -> 4.0; index 3. 1 -> 1.0`

I've attempted this by using the `toFixed` function but it is affect all the other numbers that have a decimal point. How to do I return 4.0 and 1.0 without affecting the other indexes in the array?

I am expecting these numbers to return as an integer, when using only toFixed I am returning these numbers as a string

My expected outcome is : `4.4, 4.6, 4.0, 1.0, 1.7`

```
let sumRounded = sumPercentage.map(function (percent) {
  return Math.round(percent * 10) / 10;
});
```

original console.log :

```
0: 4.4
1: 4.6
2: 4
3: 1
4: 1.7
```

---

```
let sumRounded = sumPercentage.map(function (percent) {
  return Math.round((percent * 10) / 10).toFixed(1);
});
```

console log after using toFixed

```
0: "4.0"
1: "5.0"
2: "4.0"
3: "1.0"
4: "2.0"
```

Comment: Remove `round`?

Comment: Is it ok to check if the number is a proper integer, and then apply your function? ```Number.isInteger()``` is supplied in JS for that purpose?

Comment: @Teemu is there way to do with round? I am rounded as I need these numbers are integers in order to display on a graph I am using. With using toFixed they return as a string

Comment: @VedantBang I'm not sure if im understanding your question properly, but I am expecting these numbers to return as an integer

Comment: You have to use strings for this. Numbers don't have decimal points or precision, they're just binary values, and when they're displayed they get the most compact format. You have to use `toFixed()` to format them, and that requires using a string.

Comment: @mattjkj on a graph labels are text. So you can just format the number to display number as a text. And for the actual chart values use numbers. What library are you using?

Comment: @MonteCristo I am using highcharts. I'm new to javascript so I feel that I am pretty limited in ability but with highcharts the easiest way to display but data appears to be with integers

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#format-strings

Comment: @mattjkj you're not going to display the data as strings. What you need to do is in **format the labels**. So e.g. if you want `yAxis` labels to have special format, you can supply a `formatter`. Which will take the integer value and render it as text with 2 decimals. you can see an example here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes#labels

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are giving you the wrong result:

```
Math.round((percent * 10) / 10)
```

This rounds to integers, which is why all your results ends with '.0'. You want:

```
return (Math.round(percent * 10) / 10).toFixed(1);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. This is correct but this provides me with an issue that I mentioned above. the toFixed is converting my integers to strings and i'm not familiar with javascript too well and have had issues converting these strings back to an integer which is why I wanted to use rounded. Is there a way to do this in the same inline text that I currently have using rounded?

Comment: @mattjkj If you want to display an integer like `1` with a decimal point, you will have to use `.tofFixed(1)`. If you need to convert a string back to a number, use `Number(myNumString)`.

Comment: after converting back into decimals with `Number(myNumString)` the result is displaying 1 without the decimal point again. For the graph library I am using specially I need these strings to appear as a decimal

Comment: @mattjkj To repeat, the only way in JavaScript to display an integer number like `1` as `1.0` is to convert the number to a string. What is this graph library you are using, and at what point does it require `1.0` instead of `1`? That does not sound right.